# Force TV detection in (new) Catalyst Control Center

Tags: windows-7, windows, amd-catalyst, hardware-detection

I need to force a detection of a TV because it's not auto-detected.

The problem is that, in the newer versions of Catalyst Control Center, there isn't a check-box for that any more.

EDIT: I'm using Windows 7 Professional

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7